# Algebra: Prove inequality $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$

Tags: inequality

Prove this inequality where a,b and c are random real numbers.

Comment: Maybe I can use rearrangement inequality, but I don't know what it is

Comment: I suggest you try it very hard before post here. It is difficult to get help without show any effort.

Comment: Any ideas at all?

Comment: consider multiplying the inequality by $2$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. Try by expanding
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. So from this I know that the inequality is true for any real numbers a, b and c, do not need to know they are sides of triangle.